# How to support row level security in Apache Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to have row level security enforced in Apache Spark SQL. Is that supported? (allow users to send raw HiveQL / Spark SQL queries but only show the data they are supposed to see). Is there a built in way to do so in Apache Spark?

Answer (score 2):

No Spark does not provide security at this level. If you want that kind of security  look for Accumulo DB. Accumulo was created in 2008 by the US National Security Agency and contributed to the Apache Foundation. It is a system built on top of Apache Hadoop, Apache ZooKeeper, and Apache Thrift. Written in Java, Accumulo has cell-level access labels and server-side programming mechanisms. You can refer the book - Accumulo- Application Development Table Design and Best Practices